# Self-referencing hreflang tags

Tags: html, hreflang

What does it mean when a hreflang tag is self referencing? And if I wanted to implement the following `<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com" hreflang="en-ca" />` onto a single-language website, how would I make it self referencing?

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with it, but it's quite strange -- we usually use hreflang when the website supports multiple languages, so that it is property indexed and presented by search engines.

Not sure if you are looking for x-default:

> The reserved value hreflang="x-default" is used when no other language/region matches the user's browser setting. This value is optional, but recommended, as a way for you to control the page when no languages match. A good use is to target your site's homepage where there is a clickable map that enables the user to select their country.

Reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, it did not answer my question. What does it mean when a hreflang tag is self referencing?

Comment: As an example, if you have hreflang set as "en-ca", in a Canadian English page, and the href attribute is pointing to this exact page, I believe that's "self referencing". But again, this tag is often used when you have a multi language website, and not "single-language website" as you asked.